# How to check private members in objective C unit tests?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unit-testing

Considering this class :

```
@interface SampleClass : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *_childs;
}

- (void)addChild:(ChildClass *)child;
- (void)removeChild:(ChildClass *)child;

@end
```

How can i test when i add a child if the _childs array contains one object without adding a property to access it (because i don't want allow client code to access the _childs array) ?

Comment: Objective-C doesn't have "private members";  it has instance variables.   Similar, but not quite the same.

Comment: Yes sorry, a residual C++ vocabulary ;)

Comment: The faster you let go of the complexity of C++ and embrace the simplicity of Objective-C, the faster you'll ship your app... :) (In all seriousness, I've taught hundreds of developers Objective-C over the years and the two groups that have the most difficulty are C++ and Java programmers who assume ObjC works the same way -- not saying you are doing that... just an observation).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a `@property` for it in the class extension and use the property for all accesses, that way you are testing and using the same code.

Comment: Thank you, it's the best way i have seen to do that

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I correctly understand your question, I parse it as: *While implementing `addChild:`, how do I prevent to insert objects a second time into `_childs` ?*

There are two ways: if the order of your elements doesn't matter then you should simply use a [`NSMutableSet`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableSet_Class/Reference/NSMutableSet.html) instead of an `NSMutableArray`. In this case the set takes care of everything:

```
- (void)addChild:(ChildClass *)child
{
    [_childs addObject:child];
}
```

If order *is* important, stick with the `NSMutableArray` and do it like this:

```
- (void)addChild:(ChildClass *)child
{
    if ([_childs containsObject:child]) return;

    [_childs addObject:child];
}
```

Comment: The code was just an example, it's the concept of accessing to instance variables in unit test without modifying code that i want to know

Answer (score 0):

Just make a -(int)childCount method that returns the count of the array.

Comment: Put that method in a class extension.

Comment: Yes but with this way, i need to modify my classes only to test it, i don't need a childCount method in my client code.